# function with transition.to() does not work

Tags: function, lua, coronasdk

```
local rect = display.newRect(100, 100, 100, 100)

local moving, moving2
function moving()
    transition.to(rect, {time=500, x=300, y=100, onComplete=moving2})
end

function moving2()
    transition.to(rect, {time=500, x=100, y=300, onComplete=moving})
end
```

Hi everyone. I'm a newbie to Lua, so I would like know why my rectangle is not moving on my screen with this function? When I use only this code below, it moves but stops at the end. I'd like it to repeatedly move from one side to the other:

```
local rect = display.newRect(100, 100, 100, 100)
transition.to(rect, {time=500, x=300, y=100, onComplete=moving2})
```

Comment: Did you try calling one of the functions?

Comment: It depends entirely what environment you're working in --- display, newRect, transition etc aren't standard parts of the language.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call one of the functions.  Just put:

```
moving()
```

as the last line.

Answer (score 2):

Like they said, it's not moving because you don't call 
`moving()` 
or 
`moving2()`
in your code.

Just so you know, you don't have do this complicated stuff with two different functions in the onComplete parameter. You can have the same effect on your object with one transition by changing it's easing function and setting the `iterations` parameter to `-1` for an infinite loop.

Here is a list of the available easing functions : http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/easing/index.html, as you can see the `easing.continuousLoop` function will do what you want.

You can try something like this instead :

```lua
local rect = display.newRect(100, 300, 100, 100)
transition.to(rect, {
    time = 500, 
    x = 300,
    y = 100,
    iterations = -1,
    transition = easing.continuousLoop,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

after putting at the end
    moving()
it works fine. already tested it. or you may start by
    moving2()

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone, it works well putting `moving ()` at the end

I've tried quickly the last code with `easing.continuousLoop` but it was not working exactly as i want, but i gonna check it deeply later because it could be helpful

Anyway thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, using a local object and calling it from both transitions is at some point going to cause a serious error, using your existing code pass the "rect" to each transition so it doesn't get nabbed by "still in transition."

```
local rect = display.newRect(100, 100, 100, 100)

local moving, moving2
function moving(inObj)
    if (inObj == nil) then inObj = rect end
    transition.to(inObj, {time=500, x=300, y=100, onComplete = function(iObj)
         moving2(iObj)
    end})
end

function moving2(inObj)
    transition.to(inObj, {time=500, x=100, y=300, onComplete, onComplete = function(iObj)
         moving(iObj)
    end})
end
```

**OR**

if you just want to be lazy :)

```
local rect = display.newRect(100, 100, 100, 100)
local movingIndex = 0
local moveData = {
{time = 500, x = 300, y = 100},
{time = 500, x = 300, y = 100}
}

function MoveObject(inObj)
    movingIndex = movingIndex + 1
    if (movingIndex > #moveData) then movingIndex = 1 end

    transition.to(inObj, {tag = "movingObjects", time=moveData[movingIndex].time, x=moveData[movingIndex].x, y=moveData[movingIndex].y, onComplete = function(iObj)
         MoveObject(iObj)
    end})
end

MoveObject(rect)
```

That way you just have one function and can just add animation points to the moveData table :)

By tagging the transition with tag = "movingObjects" we can pause and resume any running transition with just one call like transition.pause("movingObjects") or cancel etc. useful when you want to pause and/or are moving to another see without having to wait for a transition to end or by wrapping it in a pcall()

Just food for thought :)

**btw:: I didn't test the code above I just wrote it in this editor so may have 1 or two things that need tweeeking.**